# Simple way to request a factorization over the Gaussians

Tags: complex-numbers, factorization, pari, pari-gp

I work in the Gaussian integers and use `factor` on them with success. However, occasionally the imaginary part can vanish, but I still want a factorization in the Gaussian integers.

As an example, the program `for(j=-3, 3, print(j,": ",factor(17+j*I)))` writes:

```
-3: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 10 + 7*I, 1]
-2: [-I, 1; 2 + 17*I, 1]
-1: [-1, 1; 1 + I, 1; 1 + 2*I, 1; 2 + 5*I, 1]
0: Mat([17, 1])
1: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 2 + I, 1; 5 + 2*I, 1]
2: Mat([17 + 2*I, 1])
3: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 7 + 10*I, 1]
```

I would like the middle line in the output to be different:

```
-3: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 10 + 7*I, 1]
-2: [-I, 1; 2 + 17*I, 1]
-1: [-1, 1; 1 + I, 1; 1 + 2*I, 1; 2 + 5*I, 1]
0: [-I, 1; 4 + I, 1; 1 + 4*I, 1]
1: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 2 + I, 1; 5 + 2*I, 1]
2: Mat([17 + 2*I, 1])
3: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 7 + 10*I, 1]
```

Is there some setting to do that? Or will I have to write my own "wrapper" that treats this case specially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `factor(x, {D})` receives an optional parameter `D` indicating the factorisation domain. So just specify the target domain in call `factor(x, I)`:

```
> for(j=-3, 3, print(j,": ",factor(17+j*I, I)))
-3: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 10 + 7*I, 1]
-2: [-I, 1; 2 + 17*I, 1]
-1: [-1, 1; 1 + I, 1; 1 + 2*I, 1; 2 + 5*I, 1]
0: [-I, 1; 4 + I, 1; 1 + 4*I, 1]
1: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 2 + I, 1; 5 + 2*I, 1]
2: Mat([17 + 2*I, 1])
3: [-I, 1; 1 + I, 1; 7 + 10*I, 1]
```

Comment: What version of PARI/GP is this?

Comment: GP/PARI Version 2.11.2.

Comment: It turns out my version was 2.5 years old. And the documentation I was reading (with `??factor`) was of course also old. It looks like this feature was new in 2.10 or 2.11 which came 2 years ago. Your answer is correct; I will accept it.